# Paginação em page-blog.php no Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, query

Estou criando um tema **Wordpress** e criei uma pagina chamada **Blog** que esta usando o arquivo **page-blog.php** como modelo e o **slug** da página também é blog, onde o mesmo irá lista todos os posts de um **CPT** chamado blog, onde o mesmo eu **configurei o slug para blog**. Mas por algum motivo eu não consigo fazer a paginação funcionar e também o **carregamento do da single-blog**.

Quando a paginação funciona as internas param, e vice e versa, para resolver isso eu tive que mudar o **slug do CPT para posts**.

No entanto eu queria que a url ficasse assim:

- Página blog com paginação: [meusite.com.br/blog](http://meusite.com.br/blog)
- Interna dos posts: [meusite.com.br/blog/titulodopost](http://meusite.com.br/blog/titulodopost)

Sim eu já marquei as opções seguintes:

- **Has Archive = True**
- **Hierarchical = True**

Comment: o `slug` do CPT é *blog*, e o `slug` da página também é *blog*?

Comment: Exato, tenho certeza que não  está funcionando da forma que eu quero por conta disso, mas deve haver uma forma de resolver.

Comment: experimente desativar os permalinks e testar a paginação.

Comment: Desativando o permalink funciona, só que aí a url não fica como eu quero

Comment: Exatamente. Com permalinks ativados, quando você tem `/blog/post`, o WP se perde pois `/blog` pode ser tanto a sua página quanto o seu tipo de post. Você tem que necessariamente usar um CPT? O padrão do WP não atende? Com isso, esse problema desaparece

Comment: Não necessariamente, pode ser post padrão, só que no caso  eu usaria o category.php  aí como eu faria para ao invés de category/post, ficar blog/post ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33100/discussion-between-caio-felipe-pereira-and-sergio-machado).